# Sending email with Celery and Redis cloud

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery, django-redis

I am trying to send an email using celery queue @shared_task as below:

```
# removed imports for clarity
# For debugging
@shared_task(bind=True, name="send_email", max_retries=3, default_retry_delay=10)
def send_email(self, subject, message, from_email, to_email, **kwargs):
    """Send an email"""
    try:
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_email], **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e) # configured logger


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Send test email"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            send_email.delay(
                "Test email",
                "This is a test email",
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                "validemail@examle.com",
                fail_silently=False,
            )
            self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS("Email queued successfully"))
        except Exception as e:
            raise CommandError(e)
```

And I get

```
...celery stack trace
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'validemail@example.com': (550, b'Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.  333.kpservers.com\n(altar56.supremepanel56.com) [cpanel_server_ip]:43036 is not permitted to\nrelay through this server without authentication.')}
```

However when I use direct `send_mail` without shared_task it is successful (so it doesn't seem to be a server error)

How do I resolve this error?

I am using redis database
`redis://default:*******@********.cloud.redislabs.com:13122`